Retrieve the Boolean network specification in SBML Qual
I am attempting to retrieve the Boolean network specification from a Qualitative SBML file using libsbml in Python. However, I am unable to locate the methods for reading the Boolean network model.
How can I do this? I would like to get the Boolean network from an SBML Qual file defined as a dictionary of the form { var: formula ...} where each formula is ideally written in Simpy format.

Finally, I have identified a method for converting a SBML Boolean network into sympy formulas. However, the documentation related to SBML Qual of the libsml Python package is inadequate and lacks examples for the Qual model. The output is a dictionary representing a Boolean network descriptor called desc of the form: desc = {variable: sympy formula, ..}.
errmsg is a function printing an error according to its kind. import libsbml must be declared before.
Here is the program:
    def from_sbmlfile(filename: str) -> None:

    # STEP: Open the SBML file and get the qualitative_model model
    reader = libsbml.SBMLReader()
    document = reader.readSBML(filename)

    if document.getNumErrors() > 0:  # Check if there are no errors while reading the SBML files.
        errmsg("Error reading SBML file", document.getErrorLog().toString(), kind="WARNING")
        return {}

    model = document.getModel()  # Check whether a model exists.
    if model is None:
        errmsg("No model present in SBML file.", kind="WARNING")
        return {}

    qualitative_model = model.getPlugin("qual")  # Get the qualitative_model part of the model.
    if qualitative_model is None:  # Check whether a Qual model exists.
        errmsg("The model does not have the Qual plugin", kind="WARNING")
        return {}

    # Create a dictionary associating the string name of a variable to its corresponding Symbol.
    vars_dic = {}
    for species in qualitative_model.getListOfQualitativeSpecies():
        species_name = species.getName() if species.isSetName() else species.getId()
        vars_dic[species_name] = symbols(species_name)

    # STEP: read the formulas from transitions and convert them to sympy format.
    desc = {}
    for transition in qualitative_model.getListOfTransitions():  # Scan all the transitions.
        # Get the output variable
        output = transition.getListOfOutputs()
        if len(output) > 1:  # check whether there is a single output
            errmsg("Multiple variables assigned. List of variables", output, kind="WARNING")
            return
        else:
            variable = symbols(output[0].getQualitativeSpecies())

        # Get the formula
        logic_terms = transition.getListOfFunctionTerms()

        if len(logic_terms) == 0:  # Empty transition in SBML file, skip it.
            continue

        if len(logic_terms) > 1:  # check whether there exists a single formula only, error otherwise
            errmsg("Multiple logic terms present. Number of terms", len(logic_terms), kind="WARNING")
            return {}
        else:  # Get the SBML QUAL formula
            formula = libsbml.formulaToL3String(logic_terms[0].getMath())

        # Convert the SBML QUAL formula into sympy syntax before parsing it.
        normal_formula = re.sub(r'\|\|', '|', formula)  # convert || to |
        normal_formula = re.sub(r'&&', '&', normal_formula)  # convert && to &
        normal_formula = re.sub(r'\b(\w+)\s*==\s*1\b', r'\1', normal_formula)  # convert <var> == 1 to <var>
        normal_formula = re.sub(r'\b(\w+)\s*==\s*0\b', r'~\1', normal_formula)  # convert <var> == 0 to ~ <var>
        # Parse the formula to obtain a sympy formula and complete desc
        try:
            sympy_formula = parse_expr(normal_formula, vars_dic)
        except SyntaxError:
            errmsg("Syntax error in the following formula", normal_formula, "SYNTAX ERROR")
            return {}

        desc[variable] = sympy_formula

     return desc  # return the Boolean network descriptor

With for errmsg as example:
def errmsg(msg: str, arg="", kind: str = "ERROR") -> None:
    print(f"** {kind}:{msg}: {arg}")


I'm not super familiar with qual models, but I would guess that you could use one of the Colomoto programs (http://www.colomoto.org/index.html) to find what you want.  If not, you might need to use libsbml directly to extract the elements you need.

Thank you, but I expect a Python program, not a software.
